# How to remove the "redirect" parameter in cakephp authentication?

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.0

I want the user to be redirected to the login page if it is not logged in, but without the "redirect" parameter in the URL.
**This is my code:**

```
<code>
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ],
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Auth',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
    ]);
</code>
```

I expect the output to be
**admin/auth/login**, but the actual output is **admin/auth/login?redirect=%2Fadmin%2F**

I already looked in the documentation and found nothing.

Comment: The CakePHP version is 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by rewriting the AuthComponent class (Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent). For this I followed the documentation by creating an alias for the component (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#aliasing-components)

I rewrote the **_loginActionRedirectUrl()** function causing it to return **$this->_config['loginAction'];**

Answer (score 0):

you need to add param `'unauthorizedRedirect' => false` to your code. So your code will be look like

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => [`enter code here`
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            ]
        ],`enter code here`
    ],
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'Auth',
        'action' => 'login'
    ],
    'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
]);
```

Hope it will help you.
for more you can check [Here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-basic-authentication)

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I still need to display the login form, but without the "redirect" parameter in the URL. A brief look at the Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent class, I realized that it would be impossible to remove it using any parameters.